# iOS 9 Public Beta: Diagnostic & Usage Data not being cleared

Tags: iphone, itunes, logs, ios

Normally, syncing an iPhone to iTunes should clear on-device diagnostic and usage data.

However, I'm currently running the latest iOS 9 Public Beta, and diagnostic and usage data is not being cleared (my on-device logs now date back to 07/31/2015). Now it takes a horribly long time just to sync my iPhone because most of the syncing time is wasted on "copying diagnostic information", which is really annoying.

All of the on-device logs takes one the following two forms:

```
awdd-yyyy-mm-dd-xxxxxx-int.consolidated.metriclog[.anon]
log-sessions-yyyy-mm-dd-xxxxxx.session
```

I've also tried to clear crash reports from Xcode, to no avail.

Is there any way to force a flush without resetting the phone?

P.S. As I mentioned above, my on-device logs date back to 07/31/2015, which happens to be the day I got my Apple Watch. Is this, by any chance, related to the watch? (I read the logs but can't seem to find info about the watch, so I assume not. Anyway, it's still worth pointing out.)

Comment: To whoever voting close: this is about **publicly available** beta software.

Comment: Don’t forget to write a Feedback report to Apple 

Comment: Is this question relevant anymore?  Not sure why this was bumped...

Comment: @Hefewe1zen Because there's no accepted answer? Anyway this is hardly relevant any more.

Comment: Because its asking about ios9 beta and was posted almost 2 years ago

Answer (score 1):

There's a program called phone clean by imobie. You only need the free version. Use quick clean on it and it'll go through and delete all crash logs and diagnostic logs from your phone. I use this method all the time to free up a lot of space. https://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/

Comment: Links to the applications are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still relevant. I was having the same issue.

For me the only option was to restore my iPad from backup. iTunes should have deleted the log files after syncing, but didn't. PhoneClean, which was mentioned in another answer, said it deleted the log files but didn't. It was repeatedly trying to delete the same files.

So make an encrypted backup (so that you don't have to reenter all your passwords) and restore your device from that backup, including iOS.

Please note: A simple "Restore Backup..." does not help, you have to "Restore iPhone..." (not sure about the exact wording of the iTunes Buttons, I am running a German system).

Comment: Are you running ios9 public beta?

Comment: @TomGewecke No, but I used to run some betas to test my apps. Maybe that's why that happened.